# Remove Specified Character From String

Tags: java, string, character

In my Text Rendering system for my game, I've implemented support for coloured words.
So, if I want to render a sentence with the first word in red, and the other words in white, I can do something like this:

`"|3Hello |1there Steven!"`

When the string is rendered, it searches for a `|` character, and then looks at the number afterwards, which corresponds to a certain colour, (3 = red, 1 = white) and then it colours the rest of the string in that colour.

I want to be able to remove the `|` character as well as the number after it.

When it looks at the message and sees the `|3`, I want it to set the colour to red, and then remove the `|3`. If I use a method that replaces all the `|` followed by a number after it, when it comes to the part with `|1`, it won't set the colour to white because the `|1` isn't in the message anymore.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is a special character so you must escape it

How about this? (assuming there is only **one** number after the `'|'`)

```
str=str.substring(0,str.indexOf("|")+2).replaceAll("[|]\\d+", "")+str.substring(str.indexOf("|")+2);
```

Comment: Won't this replace all of them? As stated in the question, I can't do that.

Comment: It only replace `|` that preceeds by number(s). If you have `|3Hello |1ther|e Steven!`, then `str=str.replaceAll("[\\|]+[0-9]", "");` gives you `Hello ther|e Steven!`

Comment: I understand that, but, what I mean is that I want it to see the `|3`, process that, then ONLY replace the `|3`, because if it replaces the `|1` as well, then it can't process that when it gets to it.

Comment: ok, now I don't get it. you only want to replace the **first** occurrence of `[\\|]+[0-9]`?

Comment: I know, it's hard to understand. I'll edit my question to explain it.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, I've been looking for a solution for so long. Thanks! :)

Comment: happy to help :) #PrayForMH370

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following regex to match an `|` followed by one or more digits, then replace with empty string:

```
[|]\d+
```

Here is **[a sample](https://ideone.com/FDkfS6)**. Here is some test code:

```
String test = "|3Hello |1there Steven!";
String replaced = test.replaceAll("[|]\\d+", "");
System.out.println(replaced);
```

Comment: And here's a link on how to use regular expressions (regexes) in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Thanks for helping, although this wasn't exactly what I was looking for, I appreciate the help. :) +1

Answer (score 0):

You can split the input text by "|" and check the 1st character, assuming you not expecting to use any other | in your text.  Not sure how you want to display the colors, but here's an example using html:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] TEXT_COLORS = { 
            "FF0000", // Red
            "FF7F00", // Orange
            "FFFF00", // Yellow
            "00FF00" // Green
            };

    String input = "|3Hello |1there Steven!";
    String[] coloredPhrases = StringUtils.split(input, "|");

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i < coloredPhrases.length; i++) {
        String phrase = coloredPhrases[i];
        if (phrase.substring(0,1).matches("\\d")) {
            int colorIndex = Integer.parseInt(phrase.substring(0,1));
            output.append(String.format("<font color=#%s>%s</font>", TEXT_COLORS[colorIndex],phrase.substring(1)));
        } else {
            output.append(phrase);          
        }
    }

    System.out.print(output);
}
```